# Rendering an official PayPal button that uses REST APIs

Tags: paypal

I am beginning an integration using the PayPal REST API as I need full control over the checkout process.

I assumed that I'd be coding everything server side, so I cannot see how I should be adding the PayPal button which essentially should just call my own code which will set up the order via the API and redirect to the PayPal URL?

There is lots of online help on how to add the smart buttons etc but these look to initiate the quick checkout process via the Javascrip SDK.

Essentially I want to render an official PayPal button, but have it call a local server side page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/#add-and-modify-the-code) guide, particularly #5 of "Add and modify the code".

Be sure to read that section and click through to the demo code sample for the approval flow, https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

That's for a pure HTML/JS client -- there are also some framework-specific options..

- react-paypal-js [Storybook](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default)
- Angular and Vue, [see here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/configure-payments/single-page-app/)
- A package manager such as NPM, [paypal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/paypal-js)